# Add new post notification for buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I am at the moment building a wordpress website and I have installed the buddypress plugin. The thing is that I want the users to get notification when a author they are following posts a new post. Is there any pluggin or code that does this and if so which pluggin or do you know any code that I can add?

Thank you very much for your time and help

Comment: I think you'll find what you are looking for in this topic: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/263950/new-post-notifications-for-users-buddypress

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have looked on the code but I am new on the coding part so I am not sure on where to put the code, which file. And is it just to add the last code and thats it or do I need to do something else? Thank you very much for your time, I appreciate it!